# How can I get back Ubuntu 17.04 login screen style in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: 17.10, 17.04, lock-screen

I would like to set Ubuntu 17.04 login screen and lock screen style in Ubuntu 17.10. The swipe up screen is not a problem :)

Change this
[image: Ubuntu 17.10 lockscreen]
to this
[image]

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: The screenshots are *not* of lock-screen btw, seem to be of login screens. You should get that if you switch from GDM to LightDM, but I'm not sure how compatible Ubuntu 17.10/GNOME is with LightDM.

Comment: You will need to install lightdm and unity, which are unsupported in 17.10, to get back the old interface. If you just install lightdm, I think you'll only get it for the login screen, and the lock screen from GNOME will still be GDM.

Comment: Oops. I meant loginscreen :p

Comment: @pomsky just installing lightdm works. I didn't need to install unity. Can any of you write the answer?

Comment: @dobey is right. For lock screen it doesn't work but for login screen it works like a charm :) Is there any way to get it for lock screen too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *login* screen you desire is the default theme for *lightdm*. If you install the `lightdm` package, you can select it as your login manager. To switch between the two after being installed, you can run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` (or gdm) and select the one you wish to use.

The *lock* screen is more integral to the shell portion of the system, and to get *lightdm* as the lock screen, you will need to re-install the Unity session, and use it instead of GNOME. I do not know of a way to get GNOME shell to use *lightdm* as the lock screen.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific than that. Animations certainly would still work under GNOME.

Comment: [This](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/910/lightdm-lock-screen/) extension lock gnome with lightDM. But it has a bug. Pressing `CTRL` + `ALT` + `F7` unlocks without password :(

Comment: The animations should still work. Lightdm has nothing to do with animations inside gnome shell. As for that extension, I don't know what it does exactly. I would recommend not using it though.

Comment: Well, file a bug report then please. Comments on Ask Ubuntu is not the place to discuss such issues.

Comment: GNOME I guess. Which display manager is used should have no bearing on animations in the shell.